# Simple MariaDB custom function

Tags: mysql, mariadb, stored-functions

I am trying to write a simple database function to retrieve a value from a table.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION funcGetValue(Id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR
 BEGIN
    DECLARE theTitle VARCHAR DEFAULT ""
    SELECT MyTitle INTO theTitle FROM wp_bc_my_values WHERE MyId = Id
    RETURN theTitle
 END
```

MariaDB just gives the following message

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'BEGIN   DECLARE theTitle VARCHAR DEFAULT ""
>           SELECT MyTitle INTO theTitle FR' at line 2

I cannot see what is wrong. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Use semicolons at the end of each statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your function. Firstly, `VARCHAR` type always requires a size (e.g. `VARCHAR(50)`). Secondly, all the statements in your function need to be terminated with a `;`. Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcGetValue(Id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE theTitle VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "";
    SELECT MyTitle INTO theTitle FROM wp_bc_my_values WHERE MyId = Id;
    RETURN theTitle;
END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=586a8d876e794f74b0099e76f298088f)

Comment: Thanks. Still getting an error though.  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: I can see your demo works, and I deleted my tables and copied your code and it still errors

Comment: @StripyTiger you are probably facing a delimiter issue (see delimiter statement in MySQL's documentation)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I added DELIMITER $$ above my script.. Thanks both.

Comment: @StripyTiger sorry about the lack of response - been night time here. I'm glad Shadow was able to point you in the right direction.